# Download video from s3, works in Android and Desktop, but not in iOS

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

My website creates "presigned-url" to download files from Amazon S3.
In Desktop and Android this URL starts download perfectly using Chrome or other browser.

```
https://s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/videos.cinemedsite.com.br/888888/888888_00000000000_20180808_235040.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJQCURENNFPNNGK6A&Expires=1609383840&Signature=4lYLxgkAIt3xMer%2FPcL%2FAepwbkY%3D
```

But with this same URL on iOS (iPad and iPhone tested), the video just plays in any browser and there's no way to download. 
I've tried to download directly from aws console too, no success.

Metadata is already configured as :

```
content-disposition: attachment;filename=lixo.mp4
content-type: video/mp4 (already tried application/octet-stream also).
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Marcello

Comment: Where would it be downloaded to on iOS?

Comment: Could be in gallery, or any other place (or way) you can recommend.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS there is not a user accesable file systems with default download 'folder' as you have on a PC or MAC - i.e. you can't just click a link in the browser and have the file download to it.

With Apps like dropbox you van open a PDF file, for example, in your browser and then click the Share button and choose Dropbox to download to your device. 'Documents', another app available on the appstore, has a built in browser so is worth looking at also.

You can create your own application which will accept a URL, download it and then provide a list or directory of downloaded files. These files will only be visible by the app unless you add some functionality to save them to, for example, the gallery.

There is an AWS SDK available on Github which would be a good place to start if you are using your own app: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples